# Rendering local SVG flickers in iOS/Safari?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, safari

I'm rendering SVG icons using React and swapping between a default icon and an active icon. The SVGs are embedded in JS. On every modern browser except Safari, the transition from default to active is instant. On Safari, neither icon is shown for a brief moment. The flicker makes it look like I'm loading the active icon from the server, so there's a network delay.

Why is this happening on Safari? How can I fix it?